# How can I make EPPlus excel format to tabular instead of Compact?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot, epplus, tabular

I tried to set some of the settings such as Compact =false, CompactData = false, etc but nothing worked.

I wanted to separate the "Reviewer and Engagement instead of them in one field. I have posted two photos. The first is the output I have, Second is the one that I am trying to achieve.

```
enter code 
            //define the data range on the source sheet
            var dataRange = workSheetDataSource.Cells[workSheetDataSource.Dimension.Address];

            //create the pivot table
            var pivotTable = workSheetMgrAndEng.PivotTables.Add(workSheetMgrAndEng.Cells["A4"], dataRange, "PivotTable");

            //label field
            pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Reviewer"]);
            pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Engagement"]);
            //pivot field settings
            pivotTable.Compact = false;
            pivotTable.CompactData = false;
            pivotTable.Indent = 0;
            //pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = false;
            pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = true;
            //pivotTable.ShowMemberPropertyTips = false;
            pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;


            //data fields
            var field1 = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Engagement"]);
            field1.Name = "Count of Engagement";
            field1.Function = DataFieldFunctions.Count;

            var field2 = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Prep Complete"]);
            field2.Name = "Count of Prep Complete";
            field2.Function = DataFieldFunctions.Count;

            var field3 = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Sent Delivered"]);
            field3.Name = "Sent/Delivered";
            field3.Function = DataFieldFunctions.Count;

            var field4 = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Return to Tax Office"]);
            field4.Name = "Count of Return to Tax Office";
            field4.Function = DataFieldFunctions.Count;

            //data fields settings
            //field1.Field.Outline = false;
            field1.Field.Compact = false;
            field1.Field.ShowAll = false;
            //field1.Field.SubtotalTop = false;

            //field2.Field.Outline = false;
            field2.Field.Compact = false;
            field2.Field.ShowAll = false;
            //field2.Field.SubtotalTop = false;

            //field3.Field.Outline = false;
            field3.Field.Compact = false;
            field3.Field.ShowAll = false;
            //field3.Field.SubtotalTop = false;

            //field4.Field.Outline = false;
            field4.Field.Compact = false;
            field4.Field.ShowAll = false;
            //field4.Field.SubtotalTop = false;
```

[image: This is the output]

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]